# Got wrong record for spark-executor-<groupid> <topic> 0 even after seeking to offset <number>

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

My Spark job throws an exception as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: Got wrong record for spark-executor-test-local-npp_consumer_grp_3 <topic> 0 even after seeking to offset 29599
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:170)
```

I've disabled auto.commit (`enable.auto.commit=false`) and use Kafka API to commit the offset

```
((CanCommitOffsets) messages.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges.get());`).
```

What could be the reason for such error?
Does this error occurs due to issue with Kafka consumer side or due to my `spark-kafka` consumer program?*

After looking into [`CachedKafkaConsumer` source code](https://github.com/Stratio/spark-kafka/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/CachedKafkaConsumer.scala#L82) I think this is should be due to consecutive buffer miss (my buffer size is default size - `65536` - `receive.buffer.bytes = 65536`) but I don't see the buffer miss message - [`Buffer miss for $groupId $topic $partition $offset`](https://github.com/Stratio/spark-kafka/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/kafka010/CachedKafkaConsumer.scala#L75) in my logs.

So, I'm wondering whether it's due to buffer size?

I tried increasing `receive.buffer.bytes` to `655360` yet my `spark-kafka` consumer failed with same error. 
Could this error be due to my Kafka source be sending due to huge data

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and found the following source code in class `CachedKafkaCounsumer`  from spark-streaming. 
This is obviously due to the fact that the offset from consumer poll and the offset which the consumer seek  is not equal.

I reproduce this problem, and found out that offset from one topicAndPartition is discontinuous in Kafka

```scala
def get(offset: Long, timeout: Long): ConsumerRecord[K, V] = {
logDebug(s"Get $groupId $topic $partition nextOffset $nextOffset requested $offset")
if (offset != nextOffset) {
  logInfo(s"Initial fetch for $groupId $topic $partition $offset")
  seek(offset)
  poll(timeout)
}

if (!buffer.hasNext()) { poll(timeout) }
assert(buffer.hasNext(),
  s"Failed to get records for $groupId $topic $partition $offset after polling for $timeout")
var record = buffer.next()

if (record.offset != offset) {
  logInfo(s"Buffer miss for $groupId $topic $partition $offset")
  seek(offset)
  poll(timeout)
  assert(buffer.hasNext(),
    s"Failed to get records for $groupId $topic $partition $offset after polling for $timeout")
  record = buffer.next()
  assert(record.offset == offset,
    s"Got wrong record for $groupId $topic $partition even after seeking to offset $offset")
}

nextOffset = offset + 1
record
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48344055/kafkastreams-exactly-once-guarantee-skipping-kafka-offsets), when I was reading from topic filled using transactional producer. This issue was caused by transaction markers (commit/abort), which spark-streaming-kafka cannot read. When you run SimpleConsumerShell with --print-offsets option on this topic, you should see "gaps" between offsets.

Only solution I see now is to disable transactional producer, because newer spark-streaming-kafka is not yet implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue too and run into this link:
http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/quot-Got-wrong-record-after-seeking-to-offset-quot-issue-td30609.html

This issue was solved in version 2.4.0: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17147

I was consuming messages from a compacted topic (compressed) and using verion 2.3.0 of spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2 which cannot deal with compression.

By going to version 2.4.0 of spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2 I was able to solve it:
org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0

I also need to configure: **spark.streaming.kafka.allowNonConsecutiveOffsets=true**

My submit command looks like:

> spark-submit --class com.streamtest.Main --master spark://myparkhost:7077 --packages
>   org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0,org.apache.spark:spark-streaming_2.11:2.3.0,org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:2.3.0
>   --conf spark.streaming.kafka.allowNonConsecutiveOffsets=true /work/streamapp/build/libs/streamapp.jar